# Understanding proof of the Krull's height theorem

Tags: commutative-algebra, krull-dimension

I am reading Wikipedia, proof of the Krull's height theorem ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Krull%27s_principal_ideal_theorem ) and some question arises : Let $A$ be a noetherian ring.

[image]

I am now trying to understand the underlined statements.

Q.1. In this proof, where the property $\mathfrak{p}= \sqrt{(x_1, \dots, x_n)}$ is used?

Q.2. Why "If $\bar{\tau}$ is minimal prime over $\bar{x_1}$, then $\tau$ contains $x_1, x_2^{r_2}, \dots, x_n^{r_n}$" ?

And why from this $\tau = \mathfrak{p}$ ? Since $\mathfrak{p} = \sqrt{(x_1, \dots, x_n)}$ ? I guess that it is true since from $x_1, x_2^{r_2}, \dots , x_n^{r_n} \in \tau$, we have $x_1, x_2, \dots x_n \in \tau$ ( $\tau$ is prime ) so that $(x_1, \dots, x_n) \subseteq \tau$. Since $\mathfrak{p}$ is minimal over $(x_1, \dots , x_n)$, $\tau = \mathfrak{p}$. Correct?

**EDIT** (Other way?) : Note that $ (x_1 , x_2^{r_2}, \dots , x_n^{r_n}) = (x_1, y_2,\dots , y_n)$. **My interlude question is**, $\mathfrak{p}$ is minimal over $ (x_1 , x_2^{r_2}, \dots , x_n^{r_n})$? If so, then $\mathfrak{p}$ is minimal over $(x_1, y_2,\dots , y_n)$, and $\mathfrak{p}/ (y_2, \dots, y_n)$ is minimal over $(x_1,y_2,\dots, y_n)/(y_2,\dots, y_n)$. But this last ideal is a principal ideal in $A/(y_2,\dots, y_n)$. So

$$\operatorname{ht}(\mathfrak{p}/(y_2, \dots, y_n)) \le 1 $$

by the principal ideal theorem. This implies $\operatorname{ht}(\mathfrak{q}/(y_2, \dots, y_n))=0$. so $\mathfrak{q}$ is a prime ideal that is minimal over $(y_2, \dots, y_n)$. By induction, this implies $\operatorname{ht}(\mathfrak{q}) \le n-1$, which completes the proof. So, the above interlude question is true?

Q.3. I'm now struggling with showing $\operatorname{ht}({\mathfrak{p}}) \le n$ from $\operatorname{ht}(\mathfrak{q}) \le n-1$. If $\mathfrak{q} \subsetneq \mathfrak{p}$ are prime ideals such that there is no prime strictly between them, then $\operatorname{ht}(\mathfrak{p}) \ \le \operatorname{ht}(\mathfrak{q})+1 ( \le n)$ ? Let $L_{\mathfrak{p}}$ be the set of length of all chains of prime ideals contained in $\mathfrak{p}$ so that $\operatorname{ht}(\mathfrak{p}) = \operatorname{sup}L_{\mathfrak{p}}$ Then can we show that $\operatorname{ht}(\mathfrak{q}) +1$ is an upper bound of $L_{\mathfrak{p}}$? Can anyone helps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Q.2.** If $\bar{\mathfrak{r}}\subset \bar{A}$ (Fraktur r) is minimal prime over $\bar{x_1}$, its preimage $\mathfrak{r}\subset A$ contains $x_1$ and $y_i$ and consequently $x_i^{r_i}=y_i+a_ix_1$ (since $\mathfrak{r}$ is an ideal). I think you have deduced $\mathfrak{r}=\mathfrak{p}$ correctly.

Another way is possible: we have inclusuions $$\mathfrak{p}\supset (x_1, x_2, \dots ,x_n)\supset (x_1, x_2^{r_2}, \dots,x_n^{r_n})\supset (x_1,\dots,x_n)^N$$ for sufficiently large $N$. Taking radicals,
$$\mathfrak{p}\supset \sqrt{(x_1, x_2 ,\dots, x_n)}\supset \sqrt{(x_1, x_2^{r_2}, \dots,x_n^{r_n})}\supset \mathfrak{p}.$$

This yields $\mathfrak{p}= \sqrt{(x_1, x_2^{r_2}, \dots,x_n^{r_n})}$. The latter equation answers your interlude question affirmatively, since a prime $P$ is minimal over $Q$ if $P=\sqrt{Q}$.

**Q.3.** Note that the above argument applies to any $\mathfrak{q}$ maximal among primes strictly contained in $\mathfrak{p}$. By definition the height of $\mathfrak{p}$ is the supremum of length of prime chains in $\mathfrak{p}$. For a maximal chain, $\operatorname{ht}\mathfrak{q}\le n-1$ implies its length $\le n$. Taking their supremum we still have $\operatorname{ht}\mathfrak{p}\le n$.

Comment: Wow, thank you. For Q.3., I missed point that $\mathfrak{q}$ can be any maximal among primes strictly contained in $\mathfrak{p}$. As a 'maximal chain of prime ideals', did you mean that chain of prime ideals such that there is no prime strictly between each pair of them ?  And, for Q.2., where the minimality of $\bar{\mathfrak{r}}$ over $\bar{x_1}$ is used for showing that $\mathfrak{r}$ contains $x_1, y_i$?

Comment: And finally, you wrote, "$P$ is minimal over $Q$ if and only if $P = \sqrt{Q}$". I think that the 'only if' part may be false, since there can be more than one minimal primes over $Q$. But if $(A,P)$ is local ring with $P$ maximal ideal(as assumed in our situation), then it seems to be true. Am I pointing out well?

Comment: C.f. For the "Another way is possible" you argued. I think that there is no problem when we replace the $\mathfrak{r}$ by $(x_1, \dots, x_n)$. I think that we can avoid argument involving $\mathfrak{r}$ ! From your view point, it seems true?

Comment: @Plantation For Q.3, yes, you are right. For Q.2, we do not need minimality for that. The minimality of $\mathfrak{r}$ implies that of $\mathfrak{p}$ so that we can apply the principal ideal theorem.  For your second comment, yes. I meant ‘$P$ is the only minimal prime over… ’

Comment: O.K. Thaks for helpful hint ! ~